# Can't make queue on laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I was trying to make queue:listen, but when i try to run the command `php artisan queue:listen`, it only froze at the cmd. I've waited for 20 minutes and nothing seems to happening.

I've also tried creating new laravel project, and occur the same problem.

[image]

Comment: it is listening. for you to understand initiate a job

Comment: This command is listening for Jobs that get submitted. In order to see something happening you can open another shell and dispatch a job. 
Take a look at the docs.